# Python Type Casting with Print

Tags: python

Why does this return a class/type of 'NoneType'?

The input is a string. I have cast type to an int...

```
first_digit = print(int(two_digit_number[0]))
print(type(first_digit))
```

I know that the following will return class/type of int:

```
first_digit = int(two_digit_number[0])
```

But, I don't understand why adding print creates a NoneType class. *FYI, I'm on day 2 of learning Python.*

Comment: Any call to `print` always *returns* `None`.

Comment: Print is a function that does not return anything - that is: it returns None

Comment: The purpose of `print` is to print output to the terminal, useful mainly for debugging. If you don’t need to visualize the output, you don’t need the first print statement here.

Answer (score 1):

Functions that don't return anything return a `None` (of `NoneType`) by default. Print doesn't return what it printed or anything else, just `None`.

Answer (score 0):

`print` function doesn't have a return value. Assigning it to a variable makes its value `None` of type `NoneType`.

Answer (score 0):

`Print` is a function to print something on screen
it did not return anything to user
so it return `None`

Answer (score 0):

In its most simple view you are doing this:

```
first_digit = print(1)
```

What's the value of `first_digit` ? It is `NoneType` because you did not assign any value to the `first_digit`.

Try this instead:

```
[ins] In [14]: first_digit = 1

[ins] In [15]: print(type(first_digit))
<class 'int'>
```

Regards